# How to send a job spool by mail in SAP?

Tags: sapconnect

I need to send a job spool by email in SAP.

Exactly they are some jobs from SAP Query SQ01.

I know there are two ways to do it:

1. Directly through SQ01 when planning the job.
2. Through SM37 that probably it's easiest.

In SBWP Workplace I have added in my own list my email address to test it but I don't know how to plan the spool in order to be sent by email.

Could you please help?

P.S. The *Spool List Recipient* is unavailable. The following is the error message when I clik on it: *"There is no recipient list for the job spool"*

Thanks, best regards

Comment: Please describe the steps you want to execute in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to transaction "SCOT"

[image]

Click on "SMTP"

[image]

Fill the values correctly and click "Settings" --> "Default Domain"

[image]

Enter a default domain (example.com)

[image]

Click on "Job"

[image]

Click on "New" button and select "Schedule Job for INT"

[image]

Enter a valid "Period"

[image]

Lastly, click on "Start Immediately"

Now you can check send requests via using transaction "SCOT".